# page view count for django detail view

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views

I want to get the number of views to the details page, and I did, but I have a problem, Every time I refresh the page, the number of views increases.
I want the view to increase only once for each user, not to increase the number of visits each time the page refresh.

```
model:
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    create = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    update = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique=True)
    information = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True, default=0)
    
view:
def details(request, id):
     product_view = Product.objects.get(id=id)
     product_view.views = product_view.views  + 1
     product_view.save()
     return render(...)
```

Comment: Thought about adding another model, or many to many field to User from Product. Counting the users is would be your page view.

Answer (score 0):

You create a ManyToMany field. When a user views a page, you add the view the the user's ManyToMany and increase the view. If that relationship already exists (meaning they have visited the page before), you don't count the view, therefore creating a unique view.

Note: I'm positive there is a better solution out there but it's a start!